# Android emulator and webcam update to SDK tools?

Tags: android, android-emulator

reading the latest post on [Issue 1225](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1225#c8) from code.google.com/p/android/issues/list regarding request to have webcams working with the emulator, the issue is closed and has status "released" from January 11. I understand this as if this feature is now available.

I am trying to work out where this update to the tools can be found. It does not appear on
[Recent changes to tools](http://tools.android.com/recent), and neither of the two links on that page pointing to sources are working. Can someone point me in the direction of a repository with the latest update for the tools or tell me I have misunderstood something ?

Answer (score 0):

It is available in r14 of SDK tools for Linux and Windows.OS X support was added in r16. Update to the latest (r16) via the SDK manager.